# Converting 2D JSON array that is structured like CSV to array of objects

Tags: powershell

I'm getting through a webservice a string as a response. The string has the following two-dimensional-array structure with a header.

```
[
["name", "age","gender"],
["John doe","34","male"],
["Jane doe","23","Female"],
["Bob Doe","35","Male"]
]
```

I have to loop through all of those elements and I guess I could split my way out of it and create an array.

But is there an more elegant way to convert that string into a two-dimensional structure in powershell?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is JSON and you can use a PowerShell command to convert it to a 2D array: `$array = $response | ConvertFrom-Json`.

Comment: Yes - it works. But it's "just" an array with the header line as the part of the array og no possibility to use the header's names to get the values. The response is some kind of mix between Json and CSV - but I could live with your solution. Thanks for your answer!.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't notice that the input string is a CSV in disguise. Of course you need an additional step to interpret that array, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution that converts each row into a `PSCustomObject` (similar to what you'd get from `ConvertFrom-CSV`).

```sh
# Test input
$response = @'
[
["name", "age","gender"],
["John doe","34","male"],
["Jane doe","23","Female"],
["Bob Doe","35","Male"]
]
'@

# Convert input string to a 2D array and split it into header and data rows
$header, $dataRows = ($response | ConvertFrom-Json)

# Loop over the data rows
$data = foreach( $row in $dataRows ) {

    # Create an ordered hashtable
    $ht = [ordered]@{}

    # Loop over the columns of the current row
    for( $i = 0; $i -lt $row.Count; ++$i ){
       # Assign current column to the hashtable, using a key from the 1st row
       $ht[ $header[$i] ] = $row[$i]
    }

    # Convert the hashtable to a PSCustomObject and (implicitly) output it
    [PSCustomObject] $ht
}

# Output array of PSCustomObject
$data
```

With **PowerShell 7+**, we can replace the counting loop using a [LINQ method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-zip-2(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-1)))).

```sh
$header, $dataRows = ($response | ConvertFrom-Json)

$data = foreach( $row in $dataRows ) {
    $ht = [ordered]@{}
    [Linq.Enumerable]::Zip( [object[]] $header, [object[]] $row ).ForEach{ 
        $ht[ $_.Item1 ] = $_.Item2 
    }
    [PSCustomObject] $ht
}
```

Output:

```text
name     age gender
----     --- ------
John doe 34  male
Jane doe 23  Female
Bob Doe  35  Male
```

To get individual values:

```sh
$data[0].name # Outputs "John doe"
$data[1].age  # Outputs "23"
```

Comment: That's exactly, what I was hoping for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is RegEx and sticking with your ConverTo-Csv thought process. Well, depending on your love/hate relationship with RegEx.

```
Clear-Host
(
$Response = (@'
[
["name", "age","gender"],
["John doe","34","male"],
["Jane doe","23","Female"],
["Bob Doe","35","Male"]
]
'@ -replace '(?<=\,)\s+(?=")|[[\]]|(?<!"),').Trim() | 
ConvertFrom-Csv)

# Results
<#
name     age gender
----     --- ------
John doe 34  male  
Jane doe 23  Female
Bob Doe  35  Male  
#>

$Response.SyncRoot.Name
# Results
<#
John doe
Jane doe
Bob Doe
#>

$Response.SyncRoot.Age
# Results
<#
34
23
35
#>
```

Yet, zett42's is an elegant approach.

Comment: Regex was indeed one of my thought, but I couldn't manage to get the right pattern. This is elegant too. Thanks for your solution!

Comment: Taking shortcuts like this might be tempting, but it often fails when the data is different than expected. E. g. this valid JSON line won't be parsed correctly: `["John \"doe\"","34","ma,le"],`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no [`ConvertFrom-Json Depth` parameter](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/8199#issuecomment-439759025) in  a sense that it would stop parsing to Json at a certain level (and leave the Json string as it is).
Meaning if you want to do something similar to this, you will need convert the concerned part back to Json:

```
$response |ConvertFrom-Json | ForEach-Object {
    ($_ |ConvertTo-Json -Compress) -Replace '^\[(.*)\]$', '$1'
} |ConvertFrom-Csv
```

Comment: While seemingly elegant, this also has problems with escaped characters in the JSON: `["John \"doe\"","34","male"]`